# Force fossil to prompt for user and password on commit?

Tags: fossil

Assuming I've cloned a public repository from [chiselapp.com](http://chiselapp.com) anonymously using these commands:

```
$ fossil clone https://chiselapp.com/user/elviejo/repository/dwpt2 dwpt2.fossil
$ fossil open dwpt2.fossil
```

And now I want to commit a new file with:

```
$ fossil commit -m "these are my modifications"
```

How can Fossil prompt me for my user login and password?

PS: I know I could clone in the first place with the syntax:

```
https://user:pass@chiselapp.com
```

But let's assume I can't clone again...
Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not entirely clear from your question *which* username and password you mean. I'm going to assume you mean the user name and password used to identify yourself to the repository on chiselapp.com — in other words, the *sync* username and password, as opposed to the *commit* username.

You can change the remote URL using the [`fossil remote-url`](http://fossil-scm.org/fossil/help?cmd=remote-url) command. As it says on the help page:

> The remote-url is set automatically by a "clone" command or by any
>   "sync", "push", or "pull" command that specifies an explicit URL.
>
> The default remote-url is used by auto-syncing and by "sync", "push",
>   "pull" that omit the server URL.

So if you want to change the username used when syncing, the following should work:

```
$ fossil remote-url https://user@chiselapp.com/user/elviejo/repository/dwpt2
$ fossil commit
```

If the password is not specified, fossil will prompt you to enter it.

(Note that if the [autosync setting](http://fossil-scm.org/fossil/help/setting) is turned off, then commit will not be enough; you'd have to [sync](http://fossil-scm.org/fossil/help/sync), [push](http://fossil-scm.org/fossil/help/push) or [pull](http://fossil-scm.org/fossil/help/pull)).